# Let N = [dn,dn-1,....d2,d1,d0]10 an integer >0, in base-10 notation Let M = [d0,d1,...dn-1,dn]10, reversing the digits of N...

Tags: number-theory

Let N = [dn,dn-1,....d2,d1,d0]10 an integer >0, in base-10 notation
Let M = [d0,d1,...dn-1,dn]10, reversing the digits of N.

Show that: if n is even, N = M (mod 99). 
Show that: if n is odd, then N^2 = M^2 (mod 99)

Comment: Please use MathJax to format your question. Infos [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Is it true? I don't feel so. Consider the case when $N=24$ and $M=42$.

Comment: I have to agree with luke here. After 22 posts, it is time that you stop depending on other people to make your posts readable and put in a little effort of your own.

Comment: If you can understand what the question is asking, I feel that unnecessary as I am merely try to get some assistance in solving a problem that I do not understand. Thank you for your input.